Hyperos notification text color issue
Recently I updated my Xiaomi 13t pro to HyperOS and after a while the text color on my notification became pale gray in a white background, I don't know this is just for me that or it's a hyperos issue.
Does Anyone else have this issue or is there a fix for this, it's really annoying.
I try default theme default font and every default option,the only temporary fix is to change to dark mode then I can read notifications

I'm noticing the same issue on Poco X6 pro with Hyperos 1.0.7.0
